# Creating empty dynamic array in python for appending other arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to calculate information gain  for a certain split in a data set in python as part of an ID3 algorithm implementation.

The original data set /space is a 2D array. I figured I would create a new 3D array that will contain the partitions of the original space so that I can calculate the entropy of each of them when I am done partitioning. But I am new to python and I can't figure out how to create an empty dynamic array (list?) that I can append other 2D arrays to.

Here's what I have right now, I have tried numerous variations of declaring partitions[], and appending to it, including using numpy arrays instead but I can't figure out the correct syntax or if it is even possible:

```
def InformationGain(space, splitIndex, numPossibleValues=2):
    info = 0
    partitions = []
    for i in range (0, numPossibleValues-1):
        partitions.append([])

    #split into partitions
    for i in range (0,len(space)):
        partitions[space[i][splitIndex]].append(space[i])

    #get entropy for each partition
    for i in range (0, numPossibleValues-1):
        info += Entropy(partitions[i])*len(partitions[i])/len(space)

    return (Entropy(space) - info)

a =[[1,0,0,1],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1],]

print(InformationGain(a,1))
```

In that version I get an "IndexError: list index out of range" on the line with the append(). But it doesn't say which of the list indexes are out of range. Please help me on the right track.

Comment: It's the first one. `partitions` is empty, so `partitions[space[i]....]` is always going to fail whatever `space` is.

Comment: Thanks. How can I declare it to be the right size but still empty?

I tried "partitions = [[]*numPossibleValues]" but I get the same error. Unless all the attributes at the desired split index are the same value, then the program runs for some reason.. Probably because then it only tries to append to a single partition sublist.

Comment: You can't. A list is not an array, it has no dimension; it just contains items, which can themselves be lists.

Comment: So why doesn't the updated code work? With "partitions = [[]*numPossibleValues]" I create two lists inside partitions, since numPossibleValues is 2 right? Yet why do I still get an index error when trying to append to partitions[1] which is now a list? (I used print to verify that "space[i][splitIndex]", the index of partitions, is indeed 1 when the error happens.

Comment: Well, now it'll be the second dimension that is the problem, since `partitions[1]` is [], so `partitions[1][splitindex]` will fail whatever the value of `splitindex`. Also note that doing `[]*x` makes x references to the *same* list, so appending to one will append to them all.

Comment: But I never reference partitions[1][splitindex]
space[i][splitIndex] is the index, so the simplified whole line is:

partitions[1].append(space[i])

But I will fix all the lists having the same reference, thanks for that heads up. See the updated code in OP

Comment: Try `for i in range(0 , len(space) - 1)`

Comment: Thanks, I think it was opposite actually! I needed to remove the -1 in "numPossibleValues-1" in the range. I thought range went up to an including the max, not one below it. So partitions only got one sublist when I wanted to add two.

Comment: The code uses lists.  Is anything a `numpy` array?